# Test all alternative patterns in PEG.js

Tags: javascript, regex, peg, pegjs

I want to use PEG.js to recognize numbers in a few different formats:

```
number = integer
/ real
/ (integer/real) '^' (integer/real)
/ (integer/real) '^^' (integer/real)

real = [0-9]+ '.' [0-9]*
/ [0-9]* '.' [0-9]+

integer = [0-9]+
```

PEG.js does not look for alternatives if there is a partial match earlier in the sequence of alternatives. Most numbers start with an integer, and if they don't they start with a real number. How can I rewrite this so that it tests each alternative individually? (I am not interested in compounding the rules into fewer rules.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try matching more specific expressions first (because there's overlap between the rules, so you want PEG to match more specifically first to prevent partial matches):

```
number = ( real / integer ) '^' ( real / integer )
/  ( real / integer ) '^^' ( real / integer )
/ real
/ integer
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't capture the problem well enough with my example so I had to update it. Can this approach work with the extended example as well?

Comment: Thanks. I thought an integer or a real would be a partial match for the first rule in this case, I realize now that it's only a partial match if the pattern partially matches the input, not the other way around. +1

Comment: This problem has happened a lot in my (limited) experience with PEG.js. Whenever using `/` it's important to consider order of the rules.